# config.site_title_link = "/" or config.site_title_link = :root is not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In active admin, I gave site title, url , image . but when I click on image it does not go to url. I used active_skin also. does it create  a problem ?

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

 config.site_title = 'RetailAR'

 config.site_title_link = "/"

 config.site_title_image = "retailar.png"
 config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
 config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
 config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
 config.skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
 config.favicon = 'favicon.png'
end
```

Comment: A single line is not enough to understand your situation. Explain it with some code or example, after that  any one can help you

Comment: It could be `active_skin` Sazzad. I did not use `active_skin` before, but `config.site_title_link = "/"` seems correct way for configuring `active_admin`. See here: 
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/a0c2e26ee06dc23391b3750968a4942b23c68b73/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/active_admin.rb.erb#L12

Comment: thanks .... but not working :(